# Creating boot media (ISO download) from Microsoft without admin rights?

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, iso-image

Is there a way to create an official installation media e.g `.ISO` file from Microsoft without using admin rights? I am looking to download the official `.ISO` file for **Windows 10 as a limited use**r.

I understand Microsoft offers such a tool from their website: [Create Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Additionally some sites claim to offer `.iso` downloads of various Windows installations, but may be untrustworthy or potentially outdated.

Long back I used to download official `.ISO` from Microsoft Digital River Content website and that was for Windows 7, and could do that easily **without needing an installer nor admin rights**  but now since it is a bit difficult to get the files directly from Microsoft servers, I am looking for a way to get the file on a limited user account.

<sup>I am running Windows 10 education, non admin account, but the current system is giving me problem and I wish to get the `.iso` file of the latest April update, but not via Windows update as internet connection is not reliable</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a trying to get the EXE working without admin rights. I did try extracting it and running the files inside as a normal user, however I had no luck. But I found this post:

[Download Windows 10 ISO Without Media Creation Tool](http://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-10-iso-without-media-creation-tool/)

The Microsoft site will only let you download an ISO if you are running a non-Windows Desktop OS. However, In the case above they use Internet Explorer to emulate a windows phone.

Quite mad they don't allow you to access the ISO download from a Windows device.

I have tested this and it seems to be working still.

[image: IE Windows 10 Download]

The ISO contains the following versions:

- Windows 10 Home
- Windows 10 Home N
- Windows 10 Home Single Language
- Windows 10 Education
- Windows 10 Education N
- Windows 10 Pro
- Windows 10 Pro N
- Windows 10 Pro Education
- Windows 10 Pro Education N
- Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
- Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations

[image: DISM ISO]

Comment: I typically do this with edge - I never realised IE did this. Emulating safari always works for me

Comment: I don't know how to say thank you (besides accepting the solution) but you really helped, exactly what I was looking for ! perfect, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @xavier_fakerat glad it worked :)